# opencti - create a Call Log record against an account

Tags: opencti, log-a-call

I'm using opencti and trying to create a call log at the end of the call.

All of the samples have the call log created as a 'task' but this doesn't actually make much sense (as its a log of a call not a task).

On the account screen there is a tab 'Log a Call'.

This appears to be the logical place to insert the call.
How would I do this?

Am I mis-understanding the framework and does a Task somehow make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Logged Calls are always Tasks. There's some special functionality and visual identification (particularly in the Lightning Experience) when a Task is identified as a Call. This is done by populating the `TaskSubtype` field with the string `'Call'` at the time of creating the record.

That's what the Log a Call Quick Action does.

Note that `TaskSubtype` can *only* be populated at creation time. The field is not updateable.